# How to duplicate a git repository? (without forking)

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories, and I need to copy whole of one onto the other empty one which has different access levels from the first one. The copy and the mother repository should not be linked together.

I am new to git and it would be awesome if someone could help me with this.

Comment: not sure, but i guess you could just clone it and then use git config remote.origin.url git://new.url/proj.git
 to set the remote.origin to your new rep.

Comment: ya the link I just posted does something like that.

Comment: @rudinus I did just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

See https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Short version:

In order to make an exact duplicate, you need to perform both a bare-clone and a mirror-push:

```
mkdir foo; cd foo 
# move to a scratch dir

git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
# Make a bare clone of the repository

cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
# Mirror-push to the new repository

cd ..
rm -rf old-repository.git  
# Remove our temporary local repository
```

NOTE: the above will work fine with any remote git repo, the instructions are not specific to github

The above creates a new remote copy of the repo. Then clone it down to your working machine.

Comment: What happens if the old and new Repositories had the same name (not the same git URL). As in I just clones `Jeremy.git` into another `Jeremy.git`

Comment: This won't be an exact duplicate. Issues will not be transferred.

Comment: Does this preserve history?

Comment: @Thomas  I just did this and yes, it preserved all of my history in the copy. Note that after you push and cd into the new repo, there's still nothing there because you've pushed to the remote, so you need to do a pull

Comment: For this answer to work with GitHub, one must first create the new-repository on GitHub.

Comment: You can only push commits that were committed with one of your own verified emails.

Comment: I had already cloned my old repo but without the --bare flag and then I did a mirror push. My only concern is, does this process qualify as "copying one repo to another repo without linking them"?
what I mean by that is  can I delete my old repo.

Comment: Be aware that `git push --mirror` will *force push* to the new repository. So this command should not be repeated highhanded.

Answer (score 27):

You can also use [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy).

Note: You need to install Ruby first. Run `ruby -v` to check if you have it installed. If you don't:

Linux: run `sudo apt install ruby`, Windows: use [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/), macOS: use [Homebrew](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#homebrew)

Now install git-copy

```
gem install git-copy
```

Then you can use it

```
git copy https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Comment: How do you install gem in the first place?

This seems like the most hassle-free solution. Upvoted!

Comment: It is usually part of a Ruby install. On Ubuntu do `sudo apt install ruby`.

Comment: `"how do you install gem in the first place?"` disqualifies this from being the most hassle-free solution.

Answer (score 22):

If you are copying to GitHub, you may use the [GitHub Importer](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-your-project-to-github/) to do that for you. The original repo can even be from other version control systems.

Comment: This works perfectly and even keeps history - should be higher upvoted

Comment: I agree.  This approach is much more intuitive,  it can be done entirely within the Github GUI, and doesn't involve any of that confusing command line nonsense.  Steps: 1) In the GUI make the new repo but don't click the check box labeled "Initialize this repository with a README" After you do this Github will present you with a new page and an option labeled "…or import code from another repository."  That's it!

Comment: Doesn't work if you have read only permissions on the repo that you want to copy.

Comment: The easiest way to do the job, great! And also, if someone has read only permissions (or has 2 factor authentication on GitHub), they will need to generate a personal access token and then use that as the password (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: The hassle-free way

Answer (score 14):

**Update Nov 2021**

You can easily copy files and folder of from another VC in github now.

Steps:

1. Create a new repository
2. Click on the Import code button at the bottom

[image: Import code]

3. Paste your repository's clone URL and click Begin import

[image: Begin import]

You will be notified by email when the import is successfully completed.

Comment: best way nowadays. Must be upvoted!

Comment: Trying to import a private repository, and it keeps asking for my credentials. Didn't work.

Comment: Same here, looks like it doesn't work with private repos

Comment: For private repo's, when prompted, use a personal access token with repo read-only access instead of your password. Documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to create a new repository using all or most of the files from an existing one (i.e., as a kind of template), I find the easiest approach is to make a new repo with the desired name etc, clone it to your desktop, then just add the files and folders you want in it.

You don't get all the history etc, but you probably don't want that in this case.

Comment: That is how I used to do it, but thought there has to be a better way. There isn't. Reassuring to verify.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do it directly on Github which I find it easier.
After creating a new repository (child repository) which is empty and you want it to have the same code as the (Parent repository),
`click on the Code on the top bar. At the buttom, pick the last opion which says (...or import code from another repository). You will be prompted to enter a clone link of the repository you wish to import your code from. Paste the clone link of your (Parent repository) and press import.`

Answer (score 1):

- You need to copy the link of any repository you need to clone and work on. [(here!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdeWY.png)
- click on **Import repository** from the dropdown by clicking on the **+** on the top right corner of  the Github dashboard. [(here!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23iG9.png)
- It will redirect to the import page where you need to paste the repo link in the first input box and type in the name of the new repository. Click on Begin. [(here!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8I2B.png)
- It will then again redirect you to another page where it will clone/import the repo to your repos. It will be something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIAaV.png)
- It will mail you when the import is completed or you can click on the link underneath to open the new repo.
- You can continue working on the repo and can click on '.' on the keyboard to activate github developers and then you can continue editing it. [(here!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k1Ca.png)

I hope this answers your query.

d chipmunk

Answer (score 1):

**easier and beginner friendly Option:** If you want to avoid command lines and terminal to duplicate a repository, this is what you do:

1. Go to github page that shows all your repositories (https://github.com/your-account-name?tab=repositories)
2. Click the button "New" to create a new repository.
3. Click "repository template" button "No template". This will give you a list of your current repositories that are configured as a template.
4. Choose the repository that you want to duplicate.*
5. Finish creating the repository.

- If the repository that you would like to duplicate is not available in the list from step 3, you need to configure the repository as a template: Go to "the repository page" > Settings > "template repository" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some of the other answers here use a bare clone and then mirror push to the new repository, however this does **not** work for me and when I open the new repository after that, the files look mixed up and not as I expect.

Here is a solution that definitely works for copying the files, although it does not preserve the original repository's revision history.

1. `git clone` the repository onto your local machine.
2. `cd` into the project directory and then run `rm -rf .git` to remove all the old git metadata including commit history, etc.
3. Initialize a fresh git repository by running `git init`.
4. Run `git add . ; git commit -am "Initial commit"` - Of course you can call this commit what you want.
5. Set the origin to your new repository `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo-name` (replace the url with the url to your new repository)
6. Push it to your new repository with `git push origin master`.

Full steps:

```
mkdir my-repo
cd my-repo
git clone <repo> .
rm -rf .git
git add . ; git commit -am "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo-name
git push origin master
```

Comment: This won't preserve history.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method using the github GUI.
Click on the repository of choice, and within settings then tick template repository.
When you navigate back to the main repository. You can then create a direct copy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Safe version** on command line, without need to rewriting origin, for **public or private repository.**

Create a new repository on github **eg: "my-repo-copy"**

```
# Run the command 
git clone https://github.com/myprofil/my-repo-copy.git

# The url can be found on the repository, click the button code and https.
# You now have a empty folder my-repo-copy.

# Inside the folder my-repo-copy, run:
git clone https://github.com/myprofil/my-repo-original.git
# You now have a folder my-repo-original, go inside and copy all files/folders except .git

# Go in the folder my-repo-copy and paste, delete the folder my-repo-original

# Run
git add .
git commit -m "clone my-repo-original"
git push origin main

# If you'r branch name is main and you want to be master, after the commit, run
git checkout -b master
git push origin master
```

Comment: This won't preserve history though.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest option seems to be to enable the template repository option in your repo settings.

1. Enable `Template Repository`
   [image]
2. Go back to the repository dashboard and click `Use this template`
   [image]
3. Disable `Template Repository` again.

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal.

Create a bare clone of the repository.

> git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git

```
Mirror-push to the new repository.
```

cd old-repository.git

> git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git