Github - how to duplicate subsubrepository to another project
I have an access to two projects on Github at the same time, and I would like to pull one of the subsubrepositories to another project to include the provenance of code with URL and illustrate the collaboration between two projects.
What is the easiest way to perform it (bearing in mind that I am not expert in Github and I do not managing any of these project repositories, just contributing to both)?
So far, I've tried only cloning the subsubrepository from the first project locally and pushing it to the second project, but no provenance and link to the first project are recorded.

Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824867/how-to-duplicate-a-git-repository-on-gitlab-github-without-forking
