# How to fully migrate a git repo with with history?

Tags: git

How do i copy all branches with a full commit history, manually copying the files into the new repository location will obviously not work

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613166/how-to-duplicate-a-git-repository-without-forking

Comment: You might want to post your answer as an answer to the above question, rather than opening a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate a git repository? (without forking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613166/how-to-duplicate-a-git-repository-without-forking)

Answer (score 2):

**Clone your current remote branch**

`git clone {{git_repo_address}}`

**Set the new remote location to the current copy**

`git remote set-url origin {{new_remote_location}}`

Note: Make sure you are in the directory you cloned your repo into

**Push all branches to the new origin**

`git push -u origin --all`

`-u` - set upstream

`--all` - push all references

Comment: Not sure who up-voted this, but the description of `bare`, and of the default cloning behavior, is factually wrong.