# How to use Github for a private repository access control?

Tags: github, gitlab, bitbucket

With a repository usa scenario, we need to explore how to achieve our goal with GitHub or some other Git hosting service.

We have one private repository which is accessible (read) to a (small) group of users. We need to duplicate the repository for a user as a private repository outside of the group. And one or two users can be notified by any pushes of the user's private repository and have read access to the repository as well.

For the first requirement, I guess that we could create a private repository of an organization so that any group members can access the private repository.

For the second requirement, I don't know how to duplicate a private repository to someone outside of the organization and the duplicated repository is also private.

For the third requirement, I guess that a new organization is needed for those who needed to be notified to a private repository and have read access.

We don't have Git hosting to experience those use scenarios but want to see the feasibility. Thanks very much for your input in advance.

Comment: Why does the repository need to be duplicated? Why not just grant read access to the repository to the user that needs access? It sounds like you're working around a different problem.

Comment: To answer your question, a repository could be distributed to multiple individuals so that they could work on it themselves. Thinking of a school assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Github can fullfill 1 & 2 requirement. You can create a private repo and outsider can also clone the repo by using a temporary Personal Access Token.
Visit https://github.com/settings/tokens/new to generate the password token and make sure you define the correct [scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) of that token so that the outsider would not gain extra permission. Detail of the cloning steps can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69938166/10468516).

Answer (score 0):

from what i know, i think you could clone your first private repository and then you push to your new private repository.

Comment: A private repository usually can not be cloned for outside users.